# Как отбросить нули справа?

Tags: python, строки

Форматирую значения в строку, нужно, чтобы сохранялись только значащие разряды справа и если их нет совсем, то число вставлялось в строку как целое. То есть:

```
x = 10.0 # Типа флот
y = 12.2
'{1:тут_какой-то_хитрый_формат} - {2:такой_же_формат}'.format(x, y)

--> '10 12.2'
```

Comment: с литно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда только руками:

```
print('{0:.1f}'.format(10.0).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
```

Либо расширить функционал format:

```
from string import Formatter

class Fmt(Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, spec):
        if spec[-1] == 'p':
            spec = '{0}f'.format(spec[:-1])
            return super(Fmt, self).format_field(value, spec).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
        return super(Fmt, self).format_field(value, spec)

fmt = Fmt()
print(fmt.format('{0:.1p} - {1:.1p}', 10.0, 10.2))
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня таким образом работает формат %g для старого способа формaтирования:

```
In [47]: "%g" % 19.0
Out[47]: '19'

In [48]: "%g" % 19.1
Out[48]: '19.1'

In [50]: "%g" % 19.0001
Out[50]: '19.0001'

In [51]: "%g" % 19.00001
Out[51]: '19'
```

С помощью атрибута .n можно указать число значащих цифр:

```
In [56]: "%.8g" % 19.0000001
Out[56]: '19'

In [57]: "%.9g" % 19.0000001
Out[57]: '19.0000001'
```

Не знаю почему он так работает, вроде в документации об этом не сказано.

Comment: .n - к сожалению не после запятой, а всего. При переполнении g показывает в нормальном виде с +E, что тоже не есть айс...

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем по теме, но пока в голову только такое приходит

```
a = 10.0
x = int(a) if a - int(a) == 0.0 else a
```

но т.к. мой основной язык С++, то смущает проверка `== 0.0`.

Comment: Нормальная проверка :)
Можно, конечно, как-то так:

    if x == int(x):
      format_x = int(x)
    else:
      format_x = x

Comment: Согласен, так будет лучше.